# Returning: A full page, JSON, and a partial HTML snippet from Ruby on Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rest

I know this question has been asked **in part** a few other times on SO but I was curious about doing it a different way.  In my Ruby on Rails app I have an action called **list** on my **UsersController.rb** controller.  I want this list to respond to 3 different things

1. The page itself. Rending the whole page of users I specify
2. A JSON list of users for the page I specify
3. A partial view of just the rows for the page I'm specifying formatted as HTML.

Imagine a full page (header, footer, everything) with a table that has page 1 of users.  When I click page 2 I want to kick off an ajax request back to the same controller action to give me just the html rows for page 2.  I also want to persist my JSON API still allowing my controller to return JSON lists when asked.  I imagine it looking someting like this.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def list
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # RETURNS MY VIEW
            format.json # RETURNS MY JSON LIST
            format.partial_html # RETURNS MY PARTIAL HTML
        end
    end
end
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this in RoR? Or am I doomed into having to create another action in my controller just to return technically the same data?

Could I make this happen by specifying my own MIME type? Should I snake in the partial as an XML return type?

Comment: You should also read about rails naming conventions. It's also common practice to store your API outside your controllers(so you will not make not needed "view queries"), there's gems like grape that will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `format.js` on the third line.
2. Put the partial html on a partial, call it `app/views/users/_html_rows.html.erb`.
3. render that partial both on the full html and on the js version.

You will have `app/views/users/list.html.erb` with the full html content, which will be something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
.....
<table id="my_table"><%= render 'users/html_rows', users: @users %></table>
</body>
</html>
```

You will have `app/views/users/_html_rows.html.erb` with:

```
<tbody>
  <% users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td>user.name</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then you will have `app/views/users/list.js.erb` with:

```
$("#my_table tbody").html("<%= render 'users/html_rows', users: @users %>");
```

This probably will solve your problem.

Comment: So you're saying use format.js to return my partial view and leave the other two as is?  Is that what format.js is intended for or is it just the solution most people use?

Comment: format.js is intended to respond to a javascript request, made by jQuery, Prototype or pure javascript. If you are going to respond with a javascript code to be executed on the client (this case) or raw data to be processed via javascript is up to you. This is the most common use for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional mime type entry to work with `respond_to`. In `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`, add:

```
# htmlp means "html partial"
Mime::Type.register "text/html", :htmlp
```

In your controller you can now do:

```
def list
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
    format.htmlp { render layout: nil }
  end
end
```

And create a template called `list.htmlp.erb` with your partial content in it.